# Undefined reference to error, when using namespaces in headers in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am getting a bunch of errors saying "Undefined reference to ...", and cant understand why. I have read other questions with the error "Undefined reference to ...", but the answers doesent work for me. Here is part of my code:
main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <string>
#include <DombsMain.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(){

cout << "Armadillo version: " << arma_version::as_string() << endl;

dombsmain::initilize("test");

return 0;
}
```

dombsmain.h:

```
#ifndef DOMBSMAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define DOMBSMAIN_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Body.h"
#include "Constraint.h"
#include <Solver.h>

namespace dombsmain {

extern void initilize(std::string fileName);
extern std::string inputfileName;
...blabla
}
#endif // DOMBSMAIN_H_INCLUDED
```

dombsmain.cpp:

```
#include <DombsMain.h>
#include <BallJoint.h>
#include <dombs.h>
#indlude blabla

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

namespace dombsmain{

void initilize(string infileName){

    inputfileName = infileName;
    ..blabla
```

I think the error has something to do with namespace dombsmain. DombsMain.h is included both in main and in dombsmain.cpp, but it still says that the variables and functions in the namespace in undefined. I think it might be some conflict with including DombsMain.h int both main and dombsmain.cpp. I tried deleting the `#include <DombsMain.h>` in main.cpp, but then I couldent call `dombsmain::initilize("test");`

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compiler errors. Your code is (probably) fine, you just need to learn how to use your tools.

Comment: In particular to let the linker know you are using armadillo. http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: did you define "extern std::string inputfileName;" somewhere?

Comment: @user2950911 To be honest I dont really know what the extern keyword does. I looked it up, and it seems like I am supposed to define inputfileName again in the `DombsMain.cpp`. So I added `std::string inputfileName;` in the  `DombsMain.cpp`. Is this correct? Can I remove the extern keyword instead?

Comment: by removing the "extern", every translation unit (.cpp file) that includes this header will instantiate its own "inputfileName". This may or may not suite your case. By declaring it extern you tell your linker to trust you that this variable is defined somewhere, but not at the point where you stated extern. you could define it for example in dombsmain.cpp, as in Олег Ташланов's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to define std::string inputfileName. For example you can do it in dobsmain.cpp:

```
namespace dombsmain{

void initilize(string infileName){

    inputfileName = infileName;
    }
std::string inputfileName = "";
}
```

Comment: Why do I have to define it "again" int dombsmain.cpp? I already defined it in the header file? Can I remove the extern keyword instead?

Comment: Because "extern" modifier means that memory for variable allocated somewhere else, for example in *.cpp file, so you need to define it "twice" - once with extern and another without it.

Comment: @lijas The thing in the header is a declaration ("somewhere, there is a string named 'inputfileName'"). You also need a definition ("this particular string shall be given the name 'inputfileName'").

Comment: @ОлегТашланов @molbdnilo Okey thanks, I dont get the error anymore at least. Could I skip the extern keyword in someway, and still get it to work? If I delete the extern keyword, I get an error that says `Multiple defintions of dombsmain::inputfileName`. I dont like that I have to pretty much have the declaration/defining the variables and functions in the dombsmain namespace at two places.

Comment: @lijas If you skip extern keyword in namespace for inputfileName variable, it's became a simple global variable, witch would be defined twice in your code (in places where "DombsMain.h" included). So linker gives you an error "Multiple defintions of inputfileName variable". For solve this you need inputfileName defined as extern or static.

Comment: @ОлегТашланов Ok, I see. But how come that the `#ifndef DOMBSMAIN_H_INCLUDED, #define DOMBSMAIN_H_INCLUDED` is ignored, when I skip the extern keyword?

Comment: @lijas #ifndef DOMBSMAIN_H_INCLUDED, #define DOMBSMAIN_H_INCLUDED is needed for protection of multiple including same header in *.cpp, so it's should be worked when you would try to include  DombsMain.h in to DombsMain.cpp twice, but in your code DombsMain.h includes once in main.cpp and in DombsMain.cpp, it's acceptable behavior for guards and they don't gives you any errors. Here [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) you can read about one definition rule.